# Function gives the error ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python

I am making a program on finding the nearest house and the course of a list of houses.
These 3 functions are used to find the course and when i go to print the result in the end gives me the error:

```
File "C:/Users/ASUS/.spyder-py3/tp_1.py", line 88, in percurso
  Casas.remove(pos_i)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

```
def distancia_casas(P1, P2):
    "returns distance between points"
    delta_x = P2[0] - P1[0]
    delta_y = P2[1] - P1[1]
    distance = ((delta_x ** 2) + (delta_y ** 2)) ** 0.5
    return distance
```

```
def casa_mais_proxima(P, Casas):

    pos_inicial = Casas[0]
    pos_mini = (len(Casas), len(Casas))
    dist_mini = distancia_casas(P, pos_mini)

    for c in Casas:
        dist = distancia_casas(P, c)

        if dist < dist_mini:
            pos_mini = c
            dist_mini = dist

        elif dist == dist_mini and pos_inicial[0] > c[0]:
            pos_mini = pos_inicial

        elif dist == dist_mini and pos_inicial[0] < c[0]:
            pos_mini = c

        elif dist == dist_mini and pos_inicial[0] == c[0] and pos_inicial[1] > c[1]:
            pos_mini = pos_inicial

        elif dist == dist_mini and pos_inicial[0] == c[0] and pos_inicial[1] < c[1]:
            pos_mini = c

        elif dist >  dist_mini:
            pos_mini = pos_mini

        else:
            pos_mini = c

    return pos_mini
```

```
def percurso(Inicial, Casas):

    pos_i = Inicial

    course = [pos_i,]

    n = len(Casas) - 1

    for c in range(n):
        print(pos_i, Casas)

        pos_i = casa_mais_proxima(pos_i, Casas)

        Casas.remove(pos_i)

        course.append(pos_i)

    if (len(Casas) - 1) != 0:

        course.append(Casas[0])

    return course

print("percurso", percurso((3,2),[(0,1),(1,0),(1,2),(2,3)]))
```

Can anyone help me?
I've been battering this for 3 days and have gotten nowhere

Comment: You should not remove items from a list as you are iterating through it

Comment: Also, have you read through about the remove(x) function?

Comment: As the error states, what you're trying to remove from the list doesn't exists in first place. Maybe you'll need a `Try / Except ValueError:` that when it doesn't have it do something else. Either way, are you sure you're trying to remove the right thing? It seems you're trying to remove a number (`for c in range(n)`), should it be a string instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't remove items from a list while iterating over it. As the error message states, you are trying to remove an element that doesn't exist. Therefore:

1. You can use a list comprehension to create a new list containing only the elements you want to remove:

   ```
   no_casas = []
   for c in range(n):
       print(pos_i, Casas)

       pos_i = casa_mais_proxima(pos_i, Casas)

       no_casas.append(pos_i)

       course.append(pos_i)

   for item in no_casas:
       Casas.remove(item)
   ```

However, this approach also results in the same exception, as `casa_mais_proxima` can return the same element in `Casa` more than once (Is that the expected behavior of that function?)

Therefore:

2. You can use `Try / Except ValueError`:

   ```
   try:
       Casas.remove(pos_i)
       course.append(pos_i)


   except ValueError:
       print(str(pos_i) + " not in Casas")
   ```

Output:

```
(3, 2) [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
(2, 3) [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
(3, 3) not in Casas
(3, 3) [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
(3, 3) not in Casas
percurso [(3, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (0, 1)]
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked, the thing is that the expected result is
```[(3,2),(2,3),(1,2),(0,1),(1,0)]```

Comment: Looking at the code, I see you add to `course` in several locations (in the `try`, in the `if`).  Why do you add to `course` twice?

Comment: @dnfmar10 Also, as I mentioned in the answer, are you sure the function `casa_mais_proxima` returns the right results?

Comment: I added the if because it was a way i found to complete the course for the first test. This is a project that comes with several tests for each function.

Comment: @dnfmar10 I see. What is the logic behind `casa_mais_proxima`?

Comment: It's a function that takes a point and a list of points and using the first function returns the closest point to it using the first function (calculates the distance between points).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212441/discussion-between-dnfmar10-and-eyal-golan).

Comment: I've added `print(str(pos_mini))` just before `casa_mais_proxima` returns, and I see it never returns `(0,1)` or `(1,0)` - so the issue is defenitly there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `remove(x)` function removes a specific element.

For example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

To remove the 3 from the list, I would do:

`list1.remove(3)`

What you are doing is:

`list1.remove(2)`

The `remove(x)` function takes a specific element, not an index.

So your code would be

`Casas.remove(casas_mais_proxima[c])`.

Here, you are supplying the actual element, instead of the index of that element.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you want to remove something that doesn't exist in `Casas`.

Try this to find out the logic errors!

```
    try:
        Casas.remove(pos_i)
    except ValueError:
        print('{pos_i} not in {Casas}'.format(pos_i=pos_i, Casas=Casas))
    course.append(pos_i)
```